# A more fair way to evaluate performance than average and mode

Tags: average, median

Hi,

I want to evaluate the overall performance of a soccer team.
The team has participated in 5 tournaments so far and this is their rank in each of them

```
#4
#5
#6
#7
#200
```

you cant get the mode because there is none as they got a different rank each time, whereas using average to evaluate their overall performance would be very unfair since that single time they got a 200th would completely overshadow their other performances which were quite good. I think a fair number to represent their performance would be something between 5 and 7.

What is used in this cases?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Median](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median) sounds like what you are looking for. Using individual tournament ranks though would be reasonable only if each tournament was almost identical, otherwise the ranks would have to be weighted somehow.

You may be better off looking at individual performance game by game in each of the tournaments.

Comment: Seems like that is what I was looking for. I learned it in school but I had forgotten the name. Thank you.